# Dense net is not running with large Dataset

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have a following dataset

> image size : 256 x 256 x 3  
>  batch size = 3
>  
>   29924 images

```
def get_model():
    #base_model = application(weights='imagenet', input_shape=(image_size,image_size,3), include_top=False)
    #base_model.trainable = False
    base_model = DenseNet201(weights='imagenet', input_shape=(image_size,image_size,3), include_top=False)
    model = models.Sequential()
    model.add(base_model)
    model.add(layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D())
    model.add(layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(layers.Dense(196, activation='softmax'))
    model.summary()

    #optimizer = optimizers.SGD(lr=1e-4, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
    optimizer = optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.0001)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['acc'])

    return model
```

When I try to run the model it just stuck for a long time 
and the Memory usage is keep going up and finally die

1. How to calculate the specific memory usage for specific model?
   for my case Densenet201
2. is there way to run my model much faster way?(even running)
3. Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. How to calculate the specific memory usage for specific model? for my case Densenet201

One way to obtain the size of your model in Bytes is to multiply the number of parameters (output in your call to model.summary()) by 4 - parameters are of type Float32 and there are 8 bits in a Byte.

> 2. is there way to run my model much faster way?(even running)
> 3. Any tips?

I am not sure what you mean by 2.
In general you should:

- Check whether the model compilation step is causing the issue, in which case you should try a smaller model as your computer cannot hold DenseNet-201 in memory.
- Check whether loading the (large) dataset in one go is causing the issue. If this is the case, look into using the [ImageDataGenerator](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/) class, specifically the `.flow_from_directory` function so you only ever store current/queued batches in memory.
- If the call to `model.fit()` is the issue, try to reduce the `batch_size` parameter (warning, this will slow down training).